# Can you apply @ControllerAdvice to Spring Data Repository*Controllers generated from Repository interfaces?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a Spring Boot with entities such as...

```
@Entity
public class Thing {
    ...
}
```

...and associated repositories such as...

```
public interface ThingRepository extends Repository<Thing, Long> {
}
```

The presence of this interface causes Spring's Repository*Controller controllers to automatically handle all my needs, providing implementation for free.  This is great and works fine.

I would like all of these controllers to support JSONP callbacks though.  I have defined a separate class with the appropriate controller advice.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class JsonpAdvice extends AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice {
    public JsonpAdvice() {
        super("callback");
    }
}
```

Just defining this class once in my code base causes all *manually* created controllers to automatically be influenced by the advice.  Unfortunately the Repository*Controllers are not.

Does anyone know if there is a way to tell spring to apply my controller advice to these controllers as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brilliant...

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = {""org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc", "my.own.package"})
```

At first I was thinking the controllers were auto-generated but I refined my understanding as I typed the question and then realized how dumb the question was.  =)